# How can I allow period and comma as valid decimal point separators for floats?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, decimal, model-binding

I would like to allow both "123.45" and "123,45" as valid decimal inputs but currently "123.45" results in `"The value '123.45' is not valid for Foo"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use Globalization.  Globalization allows you to customize your numeric inputs for different locales.  Have a look at the following article:

**Globalizing ASP.NET MVC Client Validation** 
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/10/globalizing-mvc-validation.aspx

Comment: Any suggestions for a way to do it when not doing client validation?